# Why keeps the ChromiumWebBrowser form CefSharp/WinForms in loading state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp

I'm developing a plugin for a x64 application in c# with .NET-framework which needs a webbrowser. I decided to use CefSharp in verison 83.4.2 as browser framework. I'm able to initialize the CEF and can create the winforms control.
After the `IsBrowserIsInitializedChanged` was triggered, I start loading a url. The problem I have now is, that the browser flag `IsLoading` only changes from false to true, but did not change back after loading.

I tried to use the x86 version, but this is not possible in the external program. I added an eventhandler for the `LoadingStateChanged` event for tests and so I found out that the flag is only set once.

Here are some code snippets:

- used settings

```
{
   BrowserSubprocessPath = subprocess,
   CachePath = Path.Combine(cefAppdataPath, "Cache"),
   IgnoreCertificateErrors = false,
   Locale = currentCultureName,
   LocalesDirPath = Path.Combine(runtimepath, "locales"),
   LogSeverity = LogSeverity.Verbose, //Info //Verbose //Default
   LogFile = Path.Combine(cefAppdataPath, "cef.log"),
   MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true,
   PersistSessionCookies = true,
   PersistUserPreferences = true,
   RemoteDebuggingPort = 20480,
   ResourcesDirPath = Path.Combine(runtimepath),
   UserAgent = "CustomUseragent with " + CefSharp.Cef.ChromiumVersion,
   UserDataPath = Path.Combine(cefAppdataPath, "UserData")
}
_settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");
_settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("force-device-scale-factor", "1");
_settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("no-proxy-server");
```

- creating the palette for the plugin

```
InitCef();
if (!havePalette("GISX"))
    {
        log.Debug("Create palette browser");
        var browserControl = new WebBrowserControl(App, GisxApp.Startpage, null);
        browserControl.Create();
        browserControl.isInitialized.WaitOne();
        App.BrowserControl = browserControl;
        log.Debug("Add palette browser");
        myPaletteSet.Add("GISX", browserControl);
    }
```

- the constructor of WebBrowserControl

```
ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(homeurl)
{Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
WebBrowser.DownloadHandler = new WebDownloadHandler();
WebBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = new WebLifeSpanHandler(false);
WebBrowser.JsDialogHandler = (IJsDialogHandler)new WebJSDialogHandler();
WebBrowser.KeyboardHandler = new WebKeyboardHandler();
WebBrowser.MenuHandler = new WebContextMenuHandler(homeUrl);
WebBrowser.RenderProcessMessageHandler = new WebRenderBrowserProcessManager();
WebBrowser.DisplayHandler = new WebDisplayHandler();

this.Controls.Add(WebBrowser);

WebBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += new EventHandler(BrowserCreated);
WebBrowser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += new EventHandler(InitializesationChanged);
WebBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += WebBrowser_LoadingStateChanged;
```

Comment: Please provide an example that reproduces the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Providing you the code snippets is not so easy. It's splitted for reusabilitiy in multiple classes.

Comment: I cannot help you with it.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a working example.

Comment: I tried to add the important classes, but I cannot say if I missed one.

Comment: Code out of context doesn't help me unfortunately. Try creating a `MCVE` as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can build a working browser when it's not in the environment of the program I'm creating the plugin for.

Comment: I really don't have enough information to speculate what's going on. Check the cef log file, if it doesn't provide anything useful then I'd suggest stripping back your code to the bare minimum to get the browser showing. Remove all the unnecessary params, handlers, get the simplest possible thing working.

Comment: What do your handlers look like?

Comment: The handlers are currently copies from the winforms.example project. The only thing I changed was the namespace so I can find it easier in the complete project.

Comment: It looks like the problem is in the RenderBrowserProcessManager. I wanted to use it for calling ```CefSharp.BindObjectAsync()``` for two classes which are used to communication between the browser and the program the plugin is used for.

Comment: Do you mean `RenderProcessMessageHandler `? What does your implementation look like?

Comment: The methods ```OnFocusedChanged``` and ```OnUncaughtException``` only include ```Consol.WriteLine```, ```OnContextReleased``` includes a comment and the blocking Method `OnContextCreated` has a `Task.WaitAll` with two `chromiumWebBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync("CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('c#-class')")`

I could solve the problem in the meanwhile with calling it in the eventHandler for IsBrowserInitializedChanged.

Comment: You cannot wait in `OnContextCreated ` as you'd be blocking the thread. `CefSharp.BindObjectAsync` returns a promise which `EvaluateScriptAsync` cannot actually handle. Use `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync` instead.

Comment: In future when I ask to see the code please edit your question and post the actual code. Trying to show code, or even worse describe code in comments is just too messy.

Comment: I will do this in the future.
In my opinion should the original message not be changed for question that came later.

Answer (score 0):

@amaitland: Your hint with removing the handlers was the solution.

Now I need to find the problem in the handlers, because I need at least two of them.